# pyenv: BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.7 using python-build 20180424)

Tags: macos-catalina, pyenv

I just installed pyenv on macOS Catalina, and I get the following error message with the command `pyenv doctor`:

```
Cloning /Users/joel.rontynen/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-doctor/bin/.....
Installing python-pyenv-doctor...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.7 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/tl/_2700jnn5vj0q5ryygn4c4ww0000gp/T/python-build.20201014132428.46509
Results logged to /var/folders/tl/_2700jnn5vj0q5ryygn4c4ww0000gp/T/python-build.20201014132428.46509.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking readline/readline.h, presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h,... no
checking readline/rlconf.h usability... yes
checking readline/rlconf.h presence... yes
checking for readline/rlconf.h... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
configure: WARNING: OpenSSL <1.1 not installed. Checking v1.1 or beyond...
checking for OPENSSL_init_ssl in -lssl... no
configure: error: OpenSSL is not installed.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Problem(s) detected while checking system.

See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems for known solutions.
```

The log file looks like this:

```
/var/folders/tl/_2700jnn5vj0q5ryygn4c4ww0000gp/T/python-build.20201021121358.92440 ~
Cloning into 'python-pyenv-doctor'...
warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead.
done.
/var/folders/tl/_2700jnn5vj0q5ryygn4c4ww0000gp/T/python-build.20201021121358.92440/python-pyenv-doctor /var/folders/tl/_2700jnn5vj0q5ryygn4c4ww0000gp/T/python-build.20201021121358.92440 ~
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for rl_gnu_readline_p in -lreadline... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking readline/readline.h, usability... no
checking readline/readline.h, presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h,... no
checking readline/rlconf.h usability... yes
checking readline/rlconf.h presence... yes
checking for readline/rlconf.h... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
configure: WARNING: OpenSSL <1.1 not installed. Checking v1.1 or beyond...
checking for OPENSSL_init_ssl in -lssl... no
configure: error: OpenSSL is not installed.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I installed pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv using Homebrew, and the update and doctor add-ons by cloning the GitHub repository. The command `brew list` gives the following output:

```
fig             pyenv-virtualenv    xz
openssl@1.1     pyenv               readline
```

My .zshrc file looks like this:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

and .zshenv file like this:

```
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I'm not sure what other information is relevant, so you can ask for more in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was OpenSSL that was installed with Homebrew, but which "was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS provides LibreSSL." I learned this by running the command `brew info openssl`, which says

```
openssl@1.1: stable 1.1.1h (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1h (8,067 files, 18.5MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-10-14 at 12:44:32
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb
License: OpenSSL
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

The fix can be found in the message above under the line "==> Caveats". I added the export LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS lines to my ~/.zshrc file and the `pyenv doctor` command does not give any errors anymore.

Comment: Can you share step my step instructions as to how you fixed your issue? I have the same issue.

Comment: `brew reinstall openssl@1.1` was what I did to solve this.

Comment: pyenv doctor exists?